# Can you hide a marker in angular-leaflet-directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I would like to just hide a marker instead of removing it from the map. Is there a marker field that allows you to toggle whether a marker is visible.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but I just did it in CSS:

```
.leaflet-marker-pane {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the marker opacity using http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setopacity and setting it to 0.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.